# Is there a way to iterate over an n-dimensional array (where n is variable) without using recursion?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, iteration

Is there a way to iterate over an n-dimensional array (where n is variable) **without** using recursion? I'm using C++ at the moment, but I guess an answer in almost any language would do.

**EDIT**: Actually my real question is a bit different: I *actually* want to enumerate the indices of the array. Simple 2D example, with a 2x2 array: 0,0; 0,1; 1,0; 1,1.

Comment: How would that array be defined, because there are subtle differences and they matter a lot

Comment: Why is avoiding recursion a requirement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
void iterate(const std::vector<int> &dims)
{
    std::vector<int> idxs(dims.size());

    while (1)
    {
        // Print
        for (int i = 0; i < dims.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << idxs[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

        // Update
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < dims.size(); j++)
        {
            idxs[j]++;
            if (idxs[j] < dims[j]) break;
            idxs[j] = 0;
        }
        if (j == dims.size()) break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes - just remember that any multi-dimentional array in C++ (or most languages) is simply a linear region of memory. The language just helps you out by automatically multiplying any outer dimension indexes by the size / offset of that dimension.

You can therefore 'manually' walk the multidimensional array by doing the same arithmetic the language would do when you write `array[x][y][z]` - but of course you can do it for an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

yes.
if the array is 'flat' in the memory, you can just iterate from `array` to `array + n^n`.

note that the same solution with recursion will work with a loop + stack. (any recursion can be translated as loop + stack).

**EDIT**: after you editted your question: there are exactly m^n (assuming each dimension has the same number of elements `m`), a simple enumeration will be 0,1,...,(m^n)-1. access is via `array + ENUM_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote this generic helper to hash an NxM array of T.

```
template <class T, size_t N, size_t M>
    size_t hash(const T (&aa)[N][M])
{
    size_t seed = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++)
        boost::hash_combine(seed, boost::hash_range(aa[i], aa[i]+M));
    return seed;
}
```

You could use the same gist to iterate over arbitrary arrays

```
template <class T, size_t N, size_t M, class F>
    void for_each(const T (&aa)[N][M], F func)
{
    size_t seed = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (size_t j=0; j<M; j++)
        func(aa[i][j]);
}

template <class T, size_t N, size_t M, size_t L, class F>
    void for_each(const T (&aaa)[N][M][L], F func)
{
    size_t seed = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (size_t j=0; j<M; j++)
    for (size_t k=0; k<L; k++)
        func(aa[i][j][k]);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
void display(float f) {   std::cout << f << std::endl; }
// ...
float fff[1][2][3];
for_each(fff, display);
```

Comment: By *n-dimensional*, I think the OP suggests an array with 3, 4, 7, or more dimensions. 2D arrays are trivial.

Comment: That's neat, but if n varies a lot, you have to write quite a lot of code :) Plus you need to know n at compile time.